# How can I correctly use FreeMarker to iterate and print the month day from 1 to 31 into a select?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker, template-engine

I am absolutly new in **FreeMarker** and I am working on a Spring MVC application that use this template engine.

I have a very simple problem to solve using **FreeMarker**

Into a form I have a  tag in which the user can select the day of a month, something like this:

```
<select id="birth-day" name="birthDay" class="form-control selectpicker select-mm" title="Giorno"  data-validation="[NOTEMPTY, INTEGER]" data-validation-label="giorno di nascita" aria-label="seleziona il giorno di nascita" aria-required="true" tabindex="30">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    ...........................................
    ...........................................
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Actually these options are created statically but I want to create it with an iteration from 1 to 31 avoiding to write all these options inside the select tag.

Looking on the **FreeMarker** documentation it seems to me that only show how to iterate on a list: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html

But I have to do that is more like a standard loop (**for(i=1; i<=31; i++)**)

How can I implement this behavior in my page?

Comment: Not all months have 31 days...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself, this is the code:

```
<select id="birth-day" name="birthDay" class="form-control selectpicker select-mm" title="Giorno"  data-validation="[NOTEMPTY, INTEGER]" data-validation-label="giorno di nascita" aria-label="seleziona il giorno di nascita" aria-required="true" tabindex="30">

    <#assign x = 31>
    <#list 1..x as i>
        <#if i < 10>
            <option value="0${i}">0${i}</option>
        <#else>
            <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
        </#if>
    </#list>

</select>
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of `if` then you can use [this](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number)